# PDO update table with existing value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I built PHP 2 year ago and now i want to change all about database to PDO,i have some problem with update table. I use this function to update table.

```
public function update($tabel, $fild = null ,$where = null)
    {
         $update = 'UPDATE '.$tabel.' SET ';
         $set=null; $value=null;
         foreach($fild as $key => $values)
         {
             $set .= ', '.$key. ' = :'.$key;
             $value .= ', ":'.$key.'":"'.$values.'"';
         }
         $update .= substr(trim($set),1);
         $json = '{'.substr($value,1).'}';
         $param = json_decode($json,true);

         if($where != null)
         {
            $update .= ' WHERE '.$where;
         }

         $query = parent::prepare($update);
         $query->execute($param);
         $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
         return $rowcount;
    }
```

everything work fine using this

```
$updatefild = array('count' => 20);
$where = "id = '123'"; 

echo $db->update("mytable",$updatefild, $where);
```

but i get problem when i want to update row with existing row, in `mysql_query` I usually use

```
mysql_query("update mytable set count=count+1 where id='123'");
```

how i achieve that use PDO ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why are you using JSON just to decode it into an array?  That is confusing.

Secondly, if you were trying to add a number to an existing field, you don't even need prepare().

You could just do

```
PDO->query("update mytable set count=count+".intval($int)." where id='123'");
```

If you were doing prepare, you could do:

```
$stmt = PDO->prepare("update mytable set count=count+:count where id='123'");
$stmt->execute(array(':count' => 1));
```

or

```
$stmt = PDO->prepare("update mytable set count=count+? where id='123'");
$stmt->execute(array(1));
```

Edit: You wouldn't be able to do it with how your function is written as you can't bind column names.  PDO will quote it as a standard string.  You would have to find a work around, possibly including the =count in the field somehow.

Comment: ok thanks,i try later.. i want to ask something,why if i use prepare in update? as I know that prepare prevent someone doing sql injection? I new in PDO,correct me if i wrong.

Comment: Yes for strings containing user input, prepared queries are the only way to be safe.  For integers, you can just make sure they are an integer using intval() or typecasting.  You can't inject anything with an integer.

Comment: last question,i use json in update is wrong, but how i use json in select statement? i return value from table to json.how about your opinion?is best way to achieve that?

Comment: Why use json at all?  It doesn't seem like you're doing anything with `$json`

Comment: ok.i learn PDO more intensive .. thanks for your answer. i accepted that.